# Downscale, Send via Intent, and Scale up Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, jpeg, scaling

**NOTE:**
This thread has changed a bit from my original intention, please see EDIT section for more context. Mods, please let me know if I should make a new thread instead of changing this one. My argument for keeping it all in one thread, though, is to help other developers who want to send images to another Activity to realize the challenges they'll face, and the steps to take to mitigate them.

I've pulled source code from Android Camera app and notice that when they scale down the image to pass back via intent they use the following method:

```
    private Bitmap makeBitmap(byte[] data, int maxNumOfPixels) {

    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
        if (options.mCancel || options.outWidth == -1 || options.outHeight == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        options.inSampleSize = computeSampleSize(options, -1, maxNumOfPixels);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Got oom exception");
        return null;
    }
}

public static int computeSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int minSideLength, int maxNumOfPixels) {
    int initialSize = computeInitialSampleSize(options, minSideLength, maxNumOfPixels);
    int roundedSize;
    if (initialSize <= 8) {
        roundedSize = 1;
        while (roundedSize < initialSize) {
            roundedSize <<= 1;
        }
    } else {
        roundedSize = (initialSize + 7) / 8 * 8;
    }
    return roundedSize;
}

private static int computeInitialSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                            int minSideLength, int maxNumOfPixels) {
    double w = options.outWidth;
    double h = options.outHeight;

    int lowerBound = (maxNumOfPixels < 0) ? 1 :
            (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(w * h / maxNumOfPixels));
    int upperBound = (minSideLength < 0) ? 128 :
            (int) Math.min(Math.floor(w / minSideLength),
                    Math.floor(h / minSideLength));

    if (upperBound < lowerBound) {
        // return the larger one when there is no overlapping zone.
        return lowerBound;
    }

    if (maxNumOfPixels < 0 && minSideLength < 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (minSideLength < 0) {
        return lowerBound;
    } else {
        return upperBound;
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to then scale the image back up within my Activity and place it in an ImageView. How can I do this?

Currently, the image when scaled up is blurry. I'm using this method:

```
    public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    bm.recycle();
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

I pass the width and height of the screen into the above method, because my ImageView is full screen.

I think the issue is in one of the two following:

- I'm not scaling up the same way it was scaled down. I don't think this is it, because aspect ratio is maintained
- I'm doing something wrong in the code that operates the camera. In that, I've set the format to JPEG, with a jpegQuality of 50, and everything else is pretty standard. Can anybody help? Thanks!

**EDIT:** So I shouldn't scale the image down and scale it back up in the next Activity. I *should* save it (somehow) and then load it in the next Activity. What's the quickest (and most secure) way to do this? I can't let the image show in the gallery (EVER), and it needs to be QUICK.

Comment: "Currently, the image when scaled up is blurry" - without vector imagery, that's absolutely unavoidable. You'd be better off only passing the location of the image (i.e. the File location returned from the camera Intent) to the second Activity, and then re-load and downsample the Bitmap from the File to meet your second Activity's View requirements

Comment: "Currently, the image when scaled up is blurry" -- that is fairly typical of upscaling images. You lose information when you downscale an image. If you are expecting to be able to take an image, downscale it, upscale it, and wind up with the original image, you are sorely mistaken. Why not use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` and just have the camera app give you a high-resolution image in the first place?

Comment: OK, I was thinking I might be losing quality when downscaling (otherwise downscaling wouldn't really be effective). I'm not using the Camera app iteself, @CommonsWare, sorry for the confusion. I pulled the source code out here to use in my custom camera solution. The requirements are that the image is not stored in a way that will show up in Gallery on ANY phone (different phones act different ways). So, I should probably save the image and load it in the next Activity if I want to maintain quality, but how to do this while ensuring it doesn't show in Gallery is still unknown to me.

Comment: "I should probably save the image and load it in the next Activity if I want to maintain quality" -- or, don't have separate activities. Or, *carefully* pass the `Bitmap` over via a `static` field. "how to do this while ensuring it doesn't show in Gallery is still unknown to me" -- store it on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). `MediaStore` and other apps have no access to your app's part of internal storage.

Comment: I don't particularly mind saving the image. Especially because this is what the Android Camera does if, for instance, you request a crop on a photo. They save the image to the provided URI and then startActivityForResult() the Cropping Activity.  If saving works quickly, I'll use this as the solution.